# Webpack "Cannot find module" for "module": "esnext"

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4, tsconfig

I have a webpack project with this in my "main.ts" module:

```
import {Elm} from "./MainModule";
```

it fails with:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module './MainModule'.
```

but when I switch my "tsconfig.json" from `"module": "esnext"` to `"module": "commonjs"`, it works.

However, I need `"esnext"` in order to have code splitting.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try setting `moduleResolution` to  `node` in tsconfig

Comment: @samdd beautiful. Put it in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, adding `"moduleResolution": "node",` to `tsconfig.json` seems to have fixed it.

More info on it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: I'm seeing this answer in a few places, but this did not solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you set your `type` to "module" in your `package.json` file you enable ESM modules in your project.

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

But this means that Node gets strict about how it locates your import files (Module Resolution). It requires file extensions on all your import statements. If you want to import a typescript (.ts) file, and you do this

```
import blah from './blah.ts'; // Wrong
```

You will get an error because typescript inconveniently removes the .ts extension from this import statement when it compiles this file. It will compile without errors, but then fail at runtime because node needs that file extension. If you instead omit the extension and do this:

```
import blah from './blah'; // Wrong
```

Typescript will leave the extension off and compile it just fine but node will again complain at runtime. It turns out you can just import .ts files with a .js extension and Typescript will compile it and leave the extension alone.

```
import blah from './blah.js'; // Correct
```

Also try setting `module` and `moduleResolution` to "Node16"

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "Node16",
  "moduleResolution": "Node16",
  ...
}
```